# PopUP Window in Qt

Tags: qt

I am creating an application in Qt and I have a problem. I have a main window and I want that when I push a button, a popup window appears. I dont know how can I do it. I tried to call the show() method when I push the button but dont work. I think that I must use the exec() method from QApplication but I dont know how can call it if I created it in the main class.

My classes:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "popup1.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
int posiciones[10];
std::string port="";
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
for (int i=1; i<10; i++){
    if(i==7){
        posiciones[i]=90;
    }
    posiciones[i]=0;
}
//Mandar el vector para mover
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

PopUp:

```
#include "popup1.h"
#include "ui_popup1.h"

Popup1::Popup1(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Popup1)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

Popup1::~Popup1()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Anyone knows how can I show the popup window? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where is your code that handles the QPushButton click event?

Comment: yep, add signal/slot connection for your pushbutton and in there create an instance of your popup1 class. Then call ``popup1instance->exec();``

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Connect your button signal `clicked()` with `exec()` slot of your popup window:

```
connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), popupWindow, SLOT(exec()));
```

Where `pushButton` - pointer to your button, and `popupWindow` - pointer to your popup window. You can write this code in QMainWindow constructor.

Comment: so, in the popup window class I must create a exec() method? And what must do that method?

Comment: Don't create exec(), use QDialog::exec() https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdialog.html#exec

Answer (score 3):

1. Include your pop-up class in your `MainWindow.h`:

   include "popup.h"
2. Define a pointer to your pop-up class in the `MainWindow.h`:

   popup1 *mpPopUp1;
3. Create an object in the `MainWindow.cpp` file:

   mpPopUp1 = new popup1;
4. Define a slot in `MainWindow.h` and call it, for example, `showPopUp()`:

   void showPopUp();
5. Create the slot `showPopUp()` in your `MainWindow.cpp` and write the following statement inside it:

   mpPopUp1 ->show();
6. Connect your `pushButton` to the slot `showPopUp()`:

   connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showPopUp()));
7. Run you app, click on `pushButton` and voila